# need help understanding a solution of sequence and series

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, summation, riemann-zeta

On a particular problem of integration a line came up like this--
$$S_{n}=\frac{k}{k-1}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{m^{k-1}}-\frac{1}{(m+1)^{k-1}}\right)+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}m \left[\frac{1}{(m+1)^k}-\frac{1}{m^k}\right]$$
From this point they directly wrote the summation as 
$$S_{n}=\frac{k}{k-1}-\zeta(k)$$
I don't understand how they got this identity

Comment: See [Abel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $k > 1$, this series is telescoping $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{m^{k-1}}-\frac{1}{(m+1)^{k-1}}\right) = 1$$ and  $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}m\left(\frac{1}{m^{k}}-\frac{1}{(m+1)^{k}}\right) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{m}{m^{k}}-\frac{m+1}{(m+1)^{k}}+\frac{1}{(m+1)^{k}}\right) = 1+(\zeta(k)-1)$$

Comment: okay for $k \ge 2$ ? what we will get ? actually the question asked for this condition i/e $k \ge 2$

Comment: @JohnnySinns ? I just wrote the solution

Comment: That's not quite correct.  The last term should not have the $1$ added to $\zeta(k)$.

Comment: @MarkViola yep ${}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{m=1}^\infty m\left(\frac{1}{(m+1)^k}-\frac{1}{m^k}\right)&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{m}{(m+1)^k}-\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{m}{m^k}\\\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{m-1}{m^k}-\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{m}{m^k}\\\\
&=-\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{1}{m^k}\\\\
&=-\zeta(k)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks @Mark Viola

Comment: @JohnnySinns You're welcome!  My pleasure.